# If $y=\sin{(m\cos^{-1}\sqrt{x})}$ then prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}=\frac{4n^2-m^2}{4n+2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y=\sin{(m\cos^{-1}\sqrt{x})}$ then prove that $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{y_{n+1}}{y_n}=\frac{4n^2-m^2}{4n+2}$$

Note: $y_n = D^ny(x)$. To use: Libnitz rule of successive Differentiation.

**Attempt:**

$y_1=-1/2\,{\dfrac {m\cos \left( m\arccos \left( \sqrt {x} \right)  \right) 
}{\sqrt {x}\sqrt {1-x}}}$ then 
$4y_1^2x(1-x)=m^2(1-y^2)$

differentiating n times

$$8y_1y_{n+1}x(1-x)+n4(1-2x)2y_1y_n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}(-8)2y_1y_{n-1}=-2m^22yy_n$$

Problem is here $y_{n+1}, y_n, y_{n-1}$ are all present. What to do to prove the result.

Comment: What is your $y_n$?

Comment: nth derivative of y

Comment: So you have to say $y_n=y^{(n)}$.

Comment: @xpaul $y^{(n)}$ is same as $y_n$, only representations are different. I have denoted the nth derivative by $y_n$. There is no problem in terms of notation. The notation $y_n$ is also used largely.

Comment: For the second time: make it clear that $y_n = D^ny(x).$ How is anyone supposed to know what it is if you don't?

Comment: Is $m$ an $integer$ ?.

Comment: $y_n$ is mostly used  as a $n$th term of a sequence and not $n$th derivative of $y$, Please ask question with the math literature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $y= \sin(m \cos ^{-1} \sqrt{x})$ & using the notation $y_n=\frac{d^n y}{dx^n}$. You start fine ... differentiating (multiple use of the chain rule) squaring & using Pythagorus to get to
\begin{eqnarray*}
4x(1-x)y_1^{2}=m^2(1-y^2)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now differentiate this
\begin{eqnarray*}
8x(1-x)y_1 y_2 +(4-8x)y_1^{2}+2 m^2y_1 y=0
\end{eqnarray*}
Now cancel $2y_1$ and keep differentiating
\begin{eqnarray*}
4x(1-x) y_2 +2(1-2x)y_1+ m^2 y=0 \\
4x(1-x) y_3 +6(1-2x)y_2+ (m^2-4) y_1 =0 \\
4x(1-x) y_4 +10(1-2x)y_3+ (m^2-16) y_2=0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
It is easy to show by induction that
\begin{eqnarray*}
4x(1-x) y_{n+2} +2(2n+1)(1-2x)y_{n+1}+ (m^2-4n^2) y_n=0. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now substiute $x=0$ and the required result follows.

Comment: Differentiation by Libnitz rule is required.